# Login credentials in almost 5 different tables and how to go about it

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I am about to start creating a `login page` for my website.

There are various types of users like `Student`, `employee`, `manager`, `librarian` etc and I have created different tables for all. The problem comes when I try to login them because I need to go through all the tables to validate that user to log in.

I am not sure how can that be done though, I am just starting to guess.

I understand that i should have one table which stores just the login credentials of all types of user which makes it easier. But cant i just have it the way i want and that is by having separate tables for all.

There is no code to post since i am just looking for a logic so dont start downvoting me for nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you want to have 5 different login tables?

Comment: you could create a `View` with union-ed data from all 5 tables if you really want to do it this way

Comment: I dont really have a LOGIN table.They are all  just user tables and i dont want to create a separate table for credentials.

Comment: You are struggling here because your design makes it difficult. You shouldn't have 5 tables. You should have a single User table and include a UserType column to handle the specific data related to the type of user. You stated this in your question so why not do it the right way instead of making it difficult on yourself?

Comment: Best practice is usually to have single account or login table as suggested before. Sounds like more work, but it's honestly saving you time in the long run. Think about the scenarios where you have to authenticate, reset password, change password, change username, etc. You'll have to maintain that logic against each table. A properly designed view can simplify that in some scenarios (possibly with an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on the view).

Comment: The UserIds get created depending upon their roles.For example, Student would have a userId ST6889 or a professor would have a userId PR87879.Thats the main reason for having different tables @SeanLange

Comment: @JasonW - At this point of time,I have already created 5 different tables and worked a lot on the codes.What are my options right now?

Comment: You need to make the choice - which is going to be faster in the long run: start over again (which I will take longer now) or have to work around the bad design (which I would guess will take much longer over the development period).  I personally would start over again, but that's only a decision you can make

Comment: Leaving aside the wisdom of your design, what is your actual question?

Comment: Assuming you leave the tables the same, I would create a view merging all the tables, then create a trigger by "INSTEAD OF UPDATE" so that you can update the columns in the view. Then you develop your app to select and update account columns against only the view to minimize duplicate code.

Comment: @MukeshPanwar I would argue that your UserID logic is flawed. You are violating 1NF by putting additional information in a single value. What happens when a given person graduates and becomes a professor? Do they become a professor with a student "style" of UserID or do they have to get a new account? What about a professor that takes a class for fun or personal improvement? The example you posted should be two columns, not one. First column with the number and a second column with UserType.

Comment: Multiple tables sounds cool but it is will end up being a decision you regret for the life of the system. You have to constantly query multiple tables when one should be sufficient, your business logic is far more complicated than it needs to be etc, etc, etc. Consider how ridiculous it will be when you need to add another UserType. You will need to add another table, update your view and ALL of the logic around your users. Make your life easier for yourself and the people who inherit this code. Stick to a single user table.

Comment: @SeanLange - You have been really helpful.I know this is going to take time but i should get my logic right from the base.Looks like the experiment didn't go quite well.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow-up to the comment thread above, you may consider creating a view to union all of the records together for the login credentials. Then you can write your login logic against a single entity.

This still leaves the issue of what if these credentials need to change (ie: password change/reset). For that, you may consider a trigger against the view so that you can issue `UPDATE` statements against the single entity as well.

```
CREATE VIEW v_Users
AS
    SELECT
        [UserId],
        [Username],
        [Password]
    FROM [Student]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [UserId],
        [Username],
        [Password]
    FROM [employee]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [UserId],
        [Username],
        [Password]
    FROM [manager]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [UserId],
        [Username],
        [Password]
    FROM [librarian]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tg_UpdateUser ON v_Users
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Update student
    UPDATE TGT SET
        [Username] = INSERTED.[Username],
        [Password] = INSERTED.[Password]
    FROM [Student] TGT
        INNER JOIN INSERTED
            ON TGT.[UserId] = INSERTED.[UserId]

    -- Update employee
    UPDATE TGT SET
        [Username] = INSERTED.[Username],
        [Password] = INSERTED.[Password]
    FROM [employee] TGT
        INNER JOIN INSERTED
            ON TGT.[UserId] = INSERTED.[UserId]

    -- ... REPEAT FOR EACH OF YOUR TABLES

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```